# how to post data from angular service to node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-services

I am trying to post data from angular service to express routes i am not getting data to backend i recieved object from component now passing it to node but does not get there i have added bodyParser to server.js , any idea what is missing on angular side ?

search.component.ts

```
this.searchService.getSearch(this.searchObj1).subscribe(searchObj => {
         // this.detailService.changeMessage(searchObj.data)
       consle.log(searchObj);
        });
```

search.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
     getSearch(searchObj:{}) {
       let body = JSON.stringify(searchObj);
       console.log('Fac',body);
        return this.http.post('/api/search',body)
          .map(res => res.json());
      }

}
```

routes/api.js

```
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

// declare axios for making http requests
const axios = require('axios');
const API = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    router.post('/search', (req, response) => {
      // Get posts from the mock api
      console.log('CLientReq',req.body);
       request.post('http://sla/service/getHistoricEvents',
       { json: true,
         body: req.body,
         proxy:'http://one.proxy.att.com:8080',
         headers: {
         "content-type": "application/json",
         "authorization": "Basic bTA5NDg1QGNvbXMuYXR0LmNvbTpjYnVzTVNAMjAxNw=="
        }
       },
       function(err, res, body) {
         response.status(200).json(body);
       }
       );
    });
```

server.js

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');
const Oploggery = require('Oploggery');



const app = express();

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});


const port = process.env.PORT || '3000' || '4200';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);


server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there's nothing wrong with `@angular/http` and the `Http` class they are now deprecated in Angular 5, and a replacement has been available since 4.3, try the `HttpClient` class instead:

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

getSearch(searchObj:{}) {
  console.log('Fac', searchObj);
  return this.httpClient.post('/api/search', searchObj);
}
```

I suspect your issue may be with headers or encoding, `HttpClient` generally doesn't have as many of these issues as `Http` does. It also doesn't require the response to be mapped with `res.json()`.

---

You may already be doing this and you just didn't post it, but you need to export your `router` object from the `api.js` file:

`module.exports = router;`

The other issue was that the server was not sending a CORS header back to the client, the easiest way to fix this is to use the `cors` library: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

At it's simplest you can do the following to your `server.js` file:

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors'); // Add this after installing the cors library.

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./server/routes/api');
const Oploggery = require('Oploggery');
const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // Add this.
```

But I highly recommend reading up on CORS and the `cors` library if you're going to use it.

Comment: TS2551: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'?

Comment: That means you are subscribing in code you haven't shown us? You'll have to show more as the current code has no issue that I can see.

Comment: @hussain You've imported the wrong module, you need this: `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
`

Comment: @Lissy `Http` and `@angular/http` may be deprecated in Angular 5 but it is by no means the wrong module, it should still work.

Comment: i add complete service in question

Comment: Ah, my bad - sorry, your right. I've up-voted answer

Comment: ok i am subscribing in the component once i have response rendered from backend, i add component.ts in question

Comment: What do your logs reveal? The server never receives the request at all? It maybe be useful to show more of your express config.

Comment: Http and HttpClient behave different, with the old one you need to map the response to json but not with the HttpClient. Always good to review the documentation https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: server  recieved request but req is empty object angular is not passing the data

Comment: Can you log `this.searchObj1` before the request is sent?

Comment: `console.log('Fac',body)` in service is printing the object that is passed from component

Comment: Updated answer, since you have it imported anyway try the `HttpClient` class instead.

Comment: sorry to bother you but its still passing empty object to backend

Comment: added server.js to question

Comment: Okay I made a copy of your code and got it working, for me it came down to a CORS error - I'll update my answer.